# does mod_rewrite evaluate {REQUEST_FILENAME} after each rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here is the case :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/webroot/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Does the RewriteConds for the second rule use the result of the first RewriteRule ?

For instance, if i request `/onestaticfile.txt` and that file actually exists in /app/webroot, how to be sure that the final url would be `/app/webroot/onestaticfile.txt` instead of `/app/webroot/index.php?url=onestaticfile.txt` ?

Comment: In the Virtualhost (not in the .htaccess) add `RewriteEngine On`, `RewriteLogLevel 9`, `RewriteLog /path/to/a/rewrite.log` and see what happens.

Comment: In Apache 2.4 something like `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8`. `RewriteLogLevel` has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, if i request `/onestaticfile.txt` and that file actually exists in /app/webroot, how to be sure that the final url would be `/app/webroot/onestaticfile.txt` instead of `/app/webroot/index.php?url=onestaticfile.txt` ?

The RewriteConds for the second rule will get evaluated. But since `onestaticfile.txt` exists, it will fail the !-f test and the second rule won't be applied (so final url will be: `/app/webroot/onestaticfile.txt`). Likewise, if `onestaticfile.txt` doesn't exist, the 2nd rule would get applied.

In either case, when the rule is applied, an internal redirect happens and the whole thing happens again with the rewritten URI. But the 2nd time around doesn't change the base URI (without the query strings) so nothing happens the second time around.

If you had an L in the square brackets of your first rule, the 2nd rule would never be applied because rewriting will always end on the first Rule.